# Can breaking down methods into sub-methods be called OOP abstraction?

Tags: oop, abstract, abstraction

So I learned about that abstraction in OOPLs is about hiding detail and complexity.

You can encapsulate a lot of fields and methods into a class, and hide those that are only important to the inner functioning of the class but unimportant/no use to the user of the class in order to hide complexity.

I was wondering, if I have a big, fat, complex method whose body could in fact be broken down into sub-methods which hide the complexity and all the detail, then can I call this abstraction as well?

Consider this:

```
void execTask() {
    // long, dirty, complex code with all the details
}
```

——->

```
void execTask() {
    subTask1();
    subTask2();
    subTask3();
}
```

Is this organization called abstraction?

Comment: The question is likely to be closed as "opinion based". You can call it whatever you want, although I personally wouldn't call it "abstraction" in the classical sense. It's rather a form of code organization (you should usually not have "big, fat, complex" methods anyhow). One key point regarding whether it can be considered as (some form of) "abstraction" IMHO is which modifiers you are using: One could say that only the question of which methods are `public` really matters here.

Comment: @Marco13 I was new to the topic. I had in mind that abstraction might only mean the accessibility modifiers but I was not sure because I did not know how broadly should I interpret “hiding complexity”. Why do not you post your definition as answer? I think it does answer my question because it is straightforward.

Comment: One could just point to [Wikipedia: Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) here, but in one sentence (subjectively), I'd characterize abstraction roughly as ~"leaving out (or hiding) details that are not relevant to the user" ("user" referring to the user of the class or caller of a method - not to a person). So in your example, if `execTask` is the *only* public method, the remaining organization of the code does not make a difference in that regard. But let's not hastily jump to an answer. Let's wait what others have to say about this.

Comment: I also agree this is quite opinionated. In my opinion, this is abstraction in the general sense, but not in the OO sense. Yes, you are making something concrete (put bread on plate, put ham on bread, put lettuce on ham, put another bread on top) into something more abstract (make a sandwich), but I feel like abstraction in the OO sense refers more to removing irrelevant details when you create a class to model a real world thing. e.g. a `Customer` class in a movie booking system will not have a `eyeColor` or `weight` field.

Comment: @Sweeper you say remove, or hide irrelevant details? I mean, in practise, irrelevant details are those marked with “private” or “internal” modifiers?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer I mean remove. Hiding irrelevant details would be encapsulation IMO.

Comment: @Sweeper I can’t see how abstraction works in practical sense... from what are you removing the irrelevant details? You mean if you have a class called Customer then you imagine the arbitrary set of all characteristics of the human, and then filter those which are important to the given use-case?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer Yes, IMO that's what abstraction in the OO sense means.

Comment: @Sweeper I have a lot of confusing articles about key concepts of OOP. https://www.guru99.com/java-data-abstraction.html It correlates abstraction with abstract classes and methods, hiding internal details and with the definition you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194994/discussion-between-sweeper-and-patrik-nusszer).